# $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry after orbifold

Tags: hilbert-space, symmetry, conformal-field-theory, boundary-conditions

In Ginsparg's [lecture note](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9108028), section 8.5, the author mentions a **new** $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry of the **orbifold** theory: its generator is called $\tilde g$, and it maps any state $\psi \in \mathcal{H}_\text{twisted} \to - \psi$ in the twisted sector $\mathcal{H}_\text{twisted}$  of the **unorbifold compactified boson theory**.

Recall that the the **unorbifold compactified boson theory** enjoys a different global $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry mapping the field $X \to -X$, whose twisted sector gives the above $\mathcal{H}_\text{twisted}$.

I wonder: does the **unorbifold compactified boson theory** already enjoys this new symmetry generated by $\tilde g$? Or does this $\tilde g$-symmetry only make sense **after orbifold**?

(After all, it's a linear map of states preserving energy, which  seems to be a legal symmetry operation even before orbifold.)

Comment: In the theory that Ginsparg calls the unorbifold compactified boson, the twisted sector doesn't exist.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Why not? Is it illegal to consider anti-periodic boundary condition for the field $X$?

Comment: @ConnorBehan As a third instance, the Big yellow book in chapter 6 discussed the twisted sector of the vanilla scalar theory (no compactification, no orbifold). Does this sector go away once the compactification $X \sim X + 2\pi R$ is imposed? How does twisted sector come and go?

Comment: Illegal is a strong word. It's not so common because people usually think of double valuedness as a spinor thing (following arguments like section 6.2 of Ginsparg). But the answer to your previous question states that you can do this to a scalar as well to describe a system with background $\mathbb{Z}_2$ gauge fields.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Ok I see. To me, a system with a non-trivial background $\mathbb{Z}_2$ gauge field means (equivalently) that the matter field (scalar, or fermion) has a non-trivial boundary condition, and to discuss associated physics (the "twisted sector") based on that. But I still fail to understand (without orbifold) "when am I allowed  to/when should I consider twisted boundary condition/sector".